# Python Django: Customize Admin Startpage as analytical Dashboard

Tags: python, sql, django, web

I am currently developing a mobile app using Ionic and I am using Django Admin Interface as sort of Backend for adding and editing the content of my mobile app through a MySQL Database.

I currently wish to create a custom analytical dashboard for tracking the usage of the users of my mobile app in the startpage of the Django Admin. While there are some analytical packages for tracking the usage in Django, they only function for web applications.

In my case I need to gather and display aggregate data from my database (Django models & not Django models) as well for other APIs. Is there a way how can I fetch data in form of SQL queries and display them in my dashboard using Python (Django)?

And how can I extend the starting page of Django Admin to a full analytical dashboard with the named functionalities?

I am currently struggling with this as I am new to Django. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are some prebuilt admin themes which you can look into, and I personally recommend [Django Jet](https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet). You can also change directly the way that the admin templates are made and rendered looking around the contrib/admin folder on your Django installation, or you can extend the admin views and templates, take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/). Hope I could help!